# how to get a custom axis on any event of teechart

Tags: c#, teechart

Teechart is inside one user control. I have handled drag and drop event of user control, so whenever I am dropping any signal on user control it is being plotted.

If one signal is already plotted on chart and its axis (custom axis) is already created, if I am dropping another signal on the axis of already plotted signal so I want that newly plotted signal to use same axis as plotted signal but I am not able to get that axis.

Is there any event of teechart by which I can get that axis?

For example - If i drop any signal on "signal2" axis (refer attached image) then dropped signal should use signal2 axis only.

Note : All axes are custom axes.

[image]